# How to deal with if border disappeared in table?

Tags: html, html-table, row, border, col

I'm HTML beginner.I wanna make a table like this:(image below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ojq2.jpg)

And this is my code:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <table boder="1">
   <tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
    <td>04</td>
    <td>05</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>06</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">07</td>
    <td>08</td>
    <td>09</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td rowspan="2">12</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

But,the border didn't displayed in result.Where is wrong?Please,I need your HELP!

Comment: change "boder" to "border"!!

Comment: It works.thank you!<br>It was a spelling wrong!